# Parse base64 decoded string sent by multipart/form-data and get only the file using Python lambda

Tags: python, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, multipartform-data

How to parse base64 decoded string sent by multipart/form-data and get only the file using Python lambda?

```py
file_content_b64 = base64.b64decode(event['content'])
file_content = file_content_b64.decode('utf-8')
```

I'm getting the decoded file using above lines of code.
The file_content is of multipart/form-data format
How can I take the file attribute only from the form-data?

[image: How the file is sent]